# How to get url from list? BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
www = soup1.find_all('a')[1:2]
print www
```

Output:

```
[<a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>]
```

How to get `http://www.google.com` from list above ?

Comment: Since you know that there's a SET format that it will be printed (e.g the first 6 chars will always be [<a hr) you can just always print the substring which includes only the "www....com" part you desire.

Comment: @salamisalem: terrible idea. The element is not a string, anyway, but a `Tag()` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
www[0].get("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a quote from beautiful soup [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
# http://example.com/tillie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the attribute of node by 
`www[0]['href']`

Comment: Note that the OP sliced the list instead of indexed, so `www` is a list, not the `Tag` object. `www[0]['href']` would work, or better still, educate him about using indexing instead of slicing.